# Posting score to facebook

Tags: facebook, sprite-kit, slcomposeviewcontroller

I created an app in `SpriteKit` with xcode where when the game is over, it shows you your score, and I want to add the feature to post your score to facebook. Pretty much all my code is in `MyScene.m` where it can't access `presentViewController`. Only my ViewController.m file can access that, so I tried calling a instance method in Viewcontroller from Myscene.m but I can't find a way to do that. The only way I have found calling methods from other files is using `+(void)` which is a class method I think.

Myscene.m:

```
    if (location.x < 315 && location.x > 261 && location.y < 404 && location.y > 361) {
 //if you click the post to facebook button (btw, location is a variable for where you tapped on the screen)

     [ViewController facebook];
                    }
```

ViewController.m:

```
+(void)facebook{

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *facebook = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
        facebook = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [facebook setInitialText:@"initial text"];  
    }

    }
```

So that worked, and it called the facebook class method correctly, but when I put `[self presentViewController:facebook animated:YES]` after the setInitialText brackets, it gives me this error: No known class method for selector 'presentViewController:animated:'

By the way it lets me use `presentViewController` in a instance method but I can't call that method from inside the class method or from my Myscene file. Is there any way to either call an instance method from another file, or access `presentViewController` from a class method? Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't touch on this, but the error you mention is caused by your attempt to call an instance method on a class. `self` inside a  class method (`+(void)facebook`) refers to `[ViewController class]`, not `ViewController * yourViewController`. And the `ViewController` class cannot present a view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either pass a reference for your View Controller to your SKScene or you can use `NSNotificationCenter` instead. I prefer to use the latter.

First make sure you have added the Social.framework to your project.

Import the social framework into your View Controller `#import <Social/Social.h>`

Then in your View Controller's viewDidLoad method add this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(createPost:)
                                         name:@"CreatePost"
                                       object:nil];
```

Next add this method to your View Controller:

```
-(void)createPost:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *postData = [notification userInfo];
    NSString *postText = (NSString *)[postData objectForKey:@"postText"];
    NSLog(@"%@",postText);

    // build your tweet, facebook, etc...
    SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

At the appropriate location in your SKScene, (won game, lost game, etc...) add this code:

```
NSString *postText = @"I just beat the last level.";
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:postText forKey:@"postText"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CreatePost" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

The above code sends a NSNotification, with text, which your View Controller will pick up and execute the specified method.

Comment: @user3386154 - That's great. If it did the trick, please check my answer as accepted. Thanks.